# Is it OK to credit (CC BY 3.0) icons in my (GPLv2) Github project with a CREDITS.txt file?

Tags: licensing, github

I'm in the middle of uploading a project to github. My software uses some icons which are licensed: "Creative Commons ([CC BY 3.0 US](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/us/))"

Should I hardcode the credits in a... let's say "Help->About" dialog for the software or can I ship a CREDITS.txt file inside the source code tree on github. For example inside icons folder with credit to the authors and links?

Also can I use a MIT license for this case?

Comment: I don't have the time to review the licenses right this second, but in general one must provide the license text for all components with the software. At the very least, you should have text files for each license and a readme explaining which components have which licenses. Then in a help dialog you can say "portions are licensed under X, Y and Z, see the accompanying documentation for full details."

Comment: So if I understood well i can have more than 1 LICENSE file in a project like 1 in the root /src dir for the complete project and then 1 in the subdir /icons for the icons. And the content of these is the actual license text. Besides these you recommend mentioning these in the Readme file? Could it be rather inside a CREDITS.txt so the Readme stays clean from license stuff?

Comment: While organizations such as the FSF have their own standards, there is no universal way this must be done. Pick whatever makes sense for your project and make sure it is halfway intuitive. If nothing else, putting a note in the README about where to look for more info is a fail safe way to let people know. Just so long as the license info is in your distribution, you should satisfy most popular open source licenses for code and other resources (e.g. icons and documentation).

Comment: Just glancing at section 4.b in the [legal code](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/us/legalcode) this seems somewhat similar to aspects of the [original BSD / 4 clause BSD license](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html#OriginalBSD) that [has issues with GPL compatibility](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/bsd.html) because of the attribution required aspects.

Comment: @Snowman Creative Commons licences are intentionally designed to allow more simple attribution than free *software* licences do, in particular you are *not* obliged to the distribute the full legal text along with a covered work. (However, in that specific case I do not see any reason to not to do so.)

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov Thanks, I was offering the safe route based on the two minutes I had to respond. I do mean to look into this more since I may have a need to be educated on this topic soon.

Comment: @MichaelT: Per my reading, that section states, in layman's terms, that you must give attribution and that it must be as prominent as other attributions. It does not have the problems of the original BSD license, which required a specific phrase to be used in *all* advertising materials, but it seems to be on par with a requirement to mention that you are using library so-and-so.

Comment: For images only, could you attribute in the ALT text for HTML, or OnHover event for other types of apps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A software program and the icons it uses are generally not considered derived works of each other under copyright law. This means that there is no interaction between the license used for the icons and the license used for the software. The licenses do not even have to be compatible with each other.

That said, the CC-BY license of the icons does place some requirements on you, and the proposed `CREDITS.txt` file might not fulfill them.
One of the requirements is that the attribution given to the author of the icons must be in the same place and equally prominent as other attributions you give. Those other attributions would also include third-party libraries.
If you already have a `Help->About` box and/or a `LICENSES.txt` or `README.txt` file where you mention the third-party libraries you use, then you must put the attribution for the icons there as well.
If you don't have any source/library credits yet, then collecting all credits in a `CREDITS.txt` file is ok, provided that the file is distributed with all copies of your program (also the binary-only distributions).

tl;dr: Every distribution of your program with the icons must contain an attribution to the icon's author in some way. This can be a `Help->About` screen or a separate file. If you also attribute authors of other works (such as libraries), all attributions must be collected together.